# Failed to pull images from dockerhub in Kubernetes 0.15

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I followed kubernetes' guestbook, and changed image value like this, want to pull images from dockerhub.

```
"image": "redis"
```

But it failed. the log say:

> Failed to create pod infra container: image pull failed for gcr.io/google_c...

And I set preloading images instructions:

```
"imagePullPolicy":"Never"
```

I am sure about the minion have the redis image

But it also failed, and pulled from gcr.io

Comment: I found it is the "gcr.io/google_container/pause" can not pulled, so is there another way to get it?

Comment: Where are you running your cluster? And what version of docker are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in China, you won't be able to fetch images from gcr.io (including the pause image). If you want to compile your own pause image and upload it to an image registry that you have access, you can specify `--pod_infra_container_image="<registry>/pause:latest"` when launching the kubelet.

Comment: @Robert Can you tell me how to create pause image? I have a similar issue, but not able to find how to compile my own pause image. TIA.

Comment: The Dockerfile used to create the pause image is checked into the Kubernetes git repository (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/build/pause/Dockerfile). Just grab that and push it to your local registry.